# android thread stops with unknown cause

Tags: java, c#, android, multithreading, tcp

I'm communicating Android Device - PC with TCP Sockets. I sent network packets to the server succesfully but when I try to get response from the server, The thread stops I don't know cause.
Android Client :

```
public class ClientThread implements Runnable 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        try 
        {
                Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.12", 4444);

                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                out.write(msg);
                out.flush();

                Log.v("Naber", "One");

                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); // get the client message
                String inMsg = bufferedReader.readLine();
                inputStreamReader.close();
                Log.v("Naber", "Two");
                socket.close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("Hata", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Log Verbose Output :

```
09-25 22:25:37.163  15351-15532/com.mytracia.kumanda9 V/Naber﹕ One
```

I don't know why does it stops when it came to this line :

```
String inMsg = bufferedReader.readLine();
```

My Server Application with C#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 4444);
        while (true)
        {
            tcpListener.Start();
            //Program blocks on Accept() until a client connects.
            Socket soTcp = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
            Byte[] received = new Byte[1024];
            int bytesReceived = soTcp.Receive(received, received.Length, 0);
            String dataReceived = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received);
            dataReceived = dataReceived.Replace("\0", "");
            Console.WriteLine(dataReceived);
            String returningString = "Naber1";
            Byte[] returningByte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(returningString.ToCharArray());
            //Returning a confirmation string back to the client.
            soTcp.Send(returningByte, returningByte.Length, 0);
            tcpListener.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server answer with new line? "\n"

> public String readLine () Added in API level 1 Returns the next line
>   of text available from this reader. A line is represented by zero or
>   more characters followed by '\n', '\r', "\r\n" or the end of the
>   reader. The string does not include the newline sequence.
>
> Returns the contents of the line or null if no characters were read
>   before the end of the reader has been reached.

Try:

```
String returningString = "Naber1\n";
```

Comment: What did you mean? I need to send a response message like "\nNaber1" ?

Comment: @user1544101, you are welcome. I stucked before with this "new line" many times in many languages))